# Retrofit + Mediastore + API 30

Tags: android, retrofit, mediastore

I want to upload a media file stored on the device using retrofit.

All answers I find are using Mediacolumns.DATA to access the absolute file path, but Mediacolumns.DATA  is deprecated in API 30.

How can I access the media file to upload it using a Multipart retrofit request ?